# Группировка категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: c#, linq

Прежде всего, существует следующая таблица:

| id | CategoryName | ParentId | HierarchyCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Электроника | null | 1 |
| 2 | Клавиатура | 1 | 1-2 |
| 3 | Механическая | 2 | 1-2-3 |
| 4 | Мембранная | 2 | 1-2-4 |
| 5 | Монитор | 1 | 1-5 |
| 6 | Мебель | null | 6 |
| 7 | Стул | 6 | 6-7 |

Необходимо выполнить группировку категорий по самой старшей и загрузить в список (List) для последующего использования, то есть, вывод должен быть следующим:

1. Электроника
   1.1.  Клавиатура
   1.1.1. Механическая
   1.1.2. Мембранная
   1.2. Монитор
2. Мебель
   2.1. Стул

Используется EntityFramework, postgresql

Comment: Абстрагируйтесь от всего, сделайте простой, минимальный, самодостаточный пример, в котором будет заполненная коллекция нужных классов, которая покажет как выглядят ваши данные, ну а затем покажите что должно получиться ан выходе. Короче, входные и выходные данные приведите, иначе сейчас это игра на воображение.

Comment: Что такое "таблица"? Предположу, что это таблица в базе данных. Какую именно СУБД используете? Реляционку или какую-нибудь NoSql (кто вас знает)? Укажите точную версию СУБД. / Что используется для работы с БД? Сырой ADO.NET, микро-ОРМ или что? По упоминанию linq можно предположить, что какая-то LINQ-ORM. Какая именно? Их много! Наверняка EF, но... Укажите точную версию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что это ваш класс Entity:

```
class Entity
{
    public Entity(int id, string name, int? parentId)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        ParentId = parentId;

        Child = new List<Entity>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Entity> Child { get; set; }
}
```

Это тестовые данные:

```cs
var data = new[]
{
    new Entity(1, "Электроника", null),
    new Entity(2, "Клавиатура", 1),
    new Entity(3, "Механическая", 2),
    new Entity(4, "Мембранная", 2),
    new Entity(5, "Монитор", 1),
    new Entity(6, "Мебель", null),
    new Entity(7, "Стул", 6)
};
```

Тогда можно будет сделать группировку так:

```
var dictionary = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
{
    if (item.ParentId.HasValue)
    {
        var parent = dictionary[item.ParentId.Value];
        parent.Child.Add(item);
    }
}
var rootEntities = dictionary.Values.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

В `rootEntities` будет 2 родительских объекта.
Только не понял, для чего тут тег `razor`?